# Why is import * not valid syntax in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-import

I recently tried this code, just to satisfy a curiosity.

```
from * import * as *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z = *.zeros((3,3))
    print(z)
```

Can somebody tell me why `import *` is not considered a valid option?
I really would like an option to just import every library installed/recognized in one line.
Should I post a bug report, or a feature request?

Comment: `*` is not a valid variable name. That's why the `as *` doesn't work.

Comment: This would be a new feature, not a bug fix.

Comment: I understand, but the ''' from * import * ''' is still not a valid option it seems.

Comment: It's not clear at all how you would expect this to behave. How would Python know where all possible modules are and how would name conflicts be resolved?

Comment: "Every library installed" is almost certainly going to include names duplicated between modules.  You wouldn't have the slightest idea of what any given name referred to if this was actually allowed.

Comment: *“Should I post a bug report, or a feature request?”* No. It would be a feature request, but it’s guaranteed to be rejected, so don’t bother. `from specific_package import *` is already considered bad practice because it makes it impossible to tell which symbols come from where by just looking at a single source file; importing all packages like that would be much worse.

Comment: "Don't bother" is rather dismissive. There's nothing wrong with asking this question, and if the idea won't work surely we can explain why in an answer.

Comment: @IainShelvington It could recursively scan every directory in the Python search path for `.py`, `.pyc`, and `.so` files, but it would certainly be a bad idea to do so, both for performance reasons and the more concrete problem raised by jasonharper.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I said not to bother opening a feature request on the Python bug tracker. This question is very much open for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of *why* this would be a bad idea --

From the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/):

> *In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.*

It's part of Python's design rationale to avoid ambiguity, and to force developers to choose explicitly what it is they want.

When you use `from * import *`, you're importing every name defined in every module. That means you're *both* running...

`from lxml.etree.ElementTree import *`

and

`from xml.etree.ElementTree import *`

...so, how are you to know if the function `fromstring()` you have in your namespace is from `lxml.etree`, or `xml.etree`, or some other library that isn't related to XML at all in the first place?

Similarly, this means you suddenly have a `loads` function, but you don't know if it's `json.loads()` or `yaml.loads()` or, again, something 100% unrelated.

This would make code both impossible to read and impossible to write.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of *why* `import *`, `from * import *`, and other variants are not considered to be valid syntax in Python, that can be understood with a quick look at Python's grammar. The grammar for the [import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) is

```
import_stmt     ::=  "import" module ["as" identifier] ("," module ["as" identifier])*
                     | "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" identifier] ("," identifier ["as" identifier])*
                     | "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" identifier] ("," identifier ["as" identifier])* [","] ")"
                     | "from" relative_module "import" "*"
module          ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier
relative_module ::=  "."* module | "."+
```

You'll note that every token (aside from the literal text tokens) boils down to to some combination of `identifier` tokens. The [grammar of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-identifier) is a bit more complicated, but a quick skim of the rules should make it clear that the character `*` (U+002A) isn't a valid identifier. This rules out constructs like `import *` since the grammar requires a valid identifier in the position where `*` appears. The only case where `*` is allowed in an import statement is when it's explicitly permitted as a literal text token. That only occurs in the `"from" relative_module "import" "*"` alternative.